# load a different link based on time of the day

Tags: javascript, function, datetime

I need your help. After searching everywhere I cannot find the right answer for what I need. I am trying to create a javascript function to change a links href value based on time of the day. (ie I want the link that connects users to our helpdesk to deactivate at 11:45pm cst and activate at 7 am cst.) I found an old function online that gets it to work but it has a start date and I am new to javascript so I don't know how to change it to where it just uses the time of the day. So if you could please look at the code and suggest how to modify it for it to work just for the day or maybe provide another alternative I would 
appreciate it!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startDay = 5; // Start Day: 0 - 6 (Sun = 0, Mon = 1 ... Fri = 5, Sat = 6)
var startHour = 16; // Start Hour: 0 - 23
var startMin = 8; // Start Min: 0 - 59
var endDay = 5; // End Day: 0 - 6 (Sun = 0, Mon = 1 ... Fri = 5, Sat = 6)
var endHour = 16; // End Hour: 0 - 23
var endMin = 10; // End Min: 0 - 59

function alternateLink(linkObj)
{
var startTimeDate = new Date(2012, 01, 01, startHour, startMin, 00);
with (startTimeDate) while (getDay() != startDay) setDate(getDate()+1);
var startTimeDateMsecs = startTimeDate.getTime();

var endTimeDate = new Date(2012, 01, 01, endHour, endMin-1, 00);
with (endTimeDate) while (getDate() < startTimeDate.getDate()) setDate(getDate()+1);
with (endTimeDate) while (getDay() != endDay) setDate(getDate()+1);
var endTimeDateMsecs = endTimeDate.getTime();

var now = new Date();
var currentTimeDate = new Date(2012, 01, 01, now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), 00);
with (currentTimeDate) while (getDate()<startTimeDate.getDate()) setDate(getDate()+1); 
with (currentTimeDate) while (getDay() != now.getDay()) setDate(getDate()+1);
var currentTimeDateMsecs = currentTimeDate.getTime();

if (currentTimeDateMsecs >= startTimeDateMsecs && currentTimeDateMsecs <=endTimeDateMsecs) linkObj.href = 'contactus.php';} 
</script>    


<img src="default.png" alt="Time Image" id="image_id">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDate`, `getMonth` and `getFullYear` functions:

```
var now = new Date();
var month = now.getMonth()+1; //return range is 0-11, so add 1
var day = now.getDate();
var year = now.getFullYear();

var startTimeDate = new Date(year, month, day, startHour, startMin, 00);
...
var startTimeDateMsecs = startTimeDate.getTime();

var endTimeDate = new Date(year, month, day, endHour, endMin-1, 00);
...
var endTimeDateMsecs = endTimeDate.getTime();

var currentTimeDateMsecs = now.getTime();

if (currentTimeDateMsecs >= startTimeDateMsecs && currentTimeDateMsecs <=endTimeDateMsecs) 
    linkObj.href = 'contactus.php';
else
    linkObj.href = '#';
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it on Tuesday and let you know if I got it. I forgot the href for the link to display that I am using. I posted an image instead. Here it is <a href="#" onclick="alternateLink(this);">

Comment: Hey, I ended up using something even more simple with php.      <?php
$t = getdate();
$hr = $t['hours'];
if ($hr > 8) { ?>
<a href="../contactus.php"><img src="closed.png" border="0" alt="The helpdesk is currently closed"></a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="javascript:void( window.open('#', 'blank','scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=500,height=400'))"><img src="button.gif" border="0" alt=""></a>
<?php } ?>

Comment: of course you can. my answer is for the above question that concerns javascript way of doing it.